# How to install Netgear N-300 UAB adapter WNA3100 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: wireless, networking, usb, ndiswrapper, netgear

After a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04, the first thing I'm trying to do, is to setup my wireless adapter. I can see it using lsusb:

```
 beer@beer-linux:~$ lsusb
 ...
 Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0846:9020 NetGear, Inc. WNA3100(v1) Wireless-N 300 [Broadcom BCM43231] 
 ...
```

I have found a lot of dated instructions on the net and just wanted to know what the right way is to set it up on 12.04. I don't want to mess up a brand new install by tweaking things that don't need tweaking.

According to most posts, you have to install the Windows drivers using the ndiswrapper package. Is this still the right way to go? If so, it would be great if someone could write down the steps to do this under 12.04

Comment: Have you tried the Broadcom STA driver? Your hardware isn't listed, but it *may* work. It probably won't work, but it won't hurt anything either. If that doesn't work, you will need to use ndiswrapper and the windows driver. ndiswrapper isn't ideal, but it does work.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Nope I gave up after trying just about anything I could think of, but never got to trying the Broadcom STA driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the tips and advice. I spent 3 hours on the problem and finally gave up with the Netgear USB Wifi adapter. I'm done struggling with Netgear hardware on Linux.

I drove to the closest PC shop and bought an Edimax EW-77IIUAn 150 Mbps Wireless USB adapter. It worked out of the box - No installation whatsoever :-) I plugged it in, and Ubuntu immediately detected it and connected to my wireless network.

Sometimes it's just not worth the trouble to get around driver issues.

**UPDATE**

For compatible hardware it's a good idea to look at these sites:

- [Ubuntu Friendly](https://friendly.ubuntu.com/) (though it's by system rather than part)
- [Ubuntu hardware support](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport) page

For wireless cards you can go directly to the [wireless support](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported) page.