# Getting Ubuntu to recognize a BCM43231 network card what is up with terminal

Tags: wireless, broadcom, netgear

I'm trying to see if I can make ubuntu recognize my wireless adapter
which is a Netgear wna3100 that uses Broadcom  BCM43231.

```
This file lists those modules which we don't want to be loaded by
# alias expansion, usually so some other driver will be loaded for the
# device instead.

# evbug is a debug tool that should be loaded explicitly
blacklist evbug

# these drivers are very simple, the HID drivers are usually preferred
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd

# replaced by e100
blacklist eepro100

# replaced by tulip
blacklist de4x5

# causes no end of confusion by creating unexpected network interfaces
blacklist eth1394

# snd_intel8x0m can interfere with snd_intel8x0, doesn't seem to support much
# hardware on its own (Ubuntu bug #2011, #6810)
blacklist snd_intel8x0m

# Conflicts with dvb driver (which is better for handling this device)
blacklist snd_aw2

# causes failure to suspend on HP compaq nc6000 (Ubuntu: #10306)
blacklist i2c_i801

# replaced by p54pci
blacklist prism54

# replaced by b43 and ssb.
blacklist bcm43xx

# most apps now use garmin usb driver directly (Ubuntu: #114565)
blacklist garmin_gps

# replaced by asus-laptop (Ubuntu: #184721)
blacklist asus_acpi

# low-quality, just noise when being used for sound playback, causes
# hangs at desktop session start (Ubuntu: #246969)
blacklist snd_pcsp

# ugly and loud noise, getting on everyone's nerves; this should be done by a
# nice pulseaudio bing (Ubuntu: #77010)
blacklist pcspkr

# EDAC driver for amd76x clashes with the agp driver preventing the aperture
# from being initialised (Ubuntu: #297750). Blacklist so that the driver
# continues to build and is installable for the few cases where its
# really needed.
blacklist amd76x_edac
```

and when i put in the same command that gave the user from
[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-sta-wireless-card-bcm43xx)

it does absolutely nothing and is not entirely a duplicate question. As I have mentioned I have looked around and tried solutions that others have found to work

Comment: Have you reviewed: http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-sta-wireless-card-bcm43xx

Comment: i have and  i have ndisgtk installed according to the software center however ubuntu cannot find the module

Comment: **BCM43231** is NOT directly referenced in question I noted. What is current content of: **/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf** ? *You likely need to blacklist some of the 'vanilla' B43 drivers.*

Comment: To show content: **cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf**

Comment: Your comments should instead be additions / edits to your original question.

Comment: Marked as duplicate because I was lucky that a friend had the same mode. If you are talking about this model http://www.netgear.com/home/products/wireless-adapters/work-and-play/WNA3100.aspx then I can now confirm it is working with the guide provided in the duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a *lost cause*, as others have given up and used an alternate device.

[How to install Netgear N-300 UAB adapter WNA3100 on Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146576/how-to-install-netgear-n-300-uab-adapter-wna3100-on-ubuntu-12-04) (CLOSED)

*Not sure how to proceed ..*

---

The **STA** driver does not list supporting the Broadcom **BCM43231**.

Linux Wireless driver doesn't either: [Broadcom brcmsmac(PCIe) and brcmfmac(SDIO) drivers](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/brcm80211)

The Windows driver (ndisrapper) method **may work**: [UbuntuForums >> need help with Broadcom BCM43231](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11199585)

SourceForge just refers to UbuntuForums (above): [NetGear, Inc. WNA3100(v1) Wireless-N 300](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ndiswrapper/index.php?title=Netgear_WNA3100)

---

To remove / blacklist older drivers: (adapted from [Broadcom Linux hybrid wireless driver >> README.txt](http://www.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/README.txt))

Check to see if ssb, wl, b43, or bcma are loaded:

```
lsmod | grep "ssb\|wl\|b43\|bcma"
```

Blacklist these drivers, to prevent them from loading:

```
echo "blacklist ssb" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
echo "blacklist b43" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
echo "blacklist bcma" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```