# NDISWRAPPER NetGear N300, still not working

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, usb

Frustration beyond anything in Windows! I have used 12.10 on HP Laptop no issues, decided to go with 12.10 on Desktop (AMD32), every thing went fine until loading USB Wireless drivers. Loaded/Unloaded NDISWRAPPER what seems like 40 times, applied and finally did a build (`make, make install, modprobe`) and the card came up, but won't authenticate. I'm not a guru on Ubuntu, so my technical knowledge is limited. I have tried 2 cards now and no go.

Is this why Ubuntu is not "main stream". It seems so ridiculousness I can't get this to work, especially after purchase the card recommended in the hardware list. (listed as "PNP")

```
iwconfig

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lsusb

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0846:9020 NetGear, Inc. WNA3100(v1) Wireless-N 300 [Broadcom BCM43231]
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 058f:9360 Alcor Micro Corp. 8-in-1 Media Card Reader
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: REBOOTED and am getting :wlan0     IEEE 802.11g  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Bit Rate:144 Mb/s   Tx-Power:32 dBm   
          RTS thr:2347 B   Fragment thr:2346 B   
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

Comment: From ndiswrapper -l  bcmn43xx32 : driver installed
              device (0846:9020) present

Answer (score 0):

Ndiswrapper is totally **obsolete** and causes problem than solving it.

In old days, Ndiswrapper was a successful tool but as of today, when almost all hardware manufactures are providing drivers, it must be used as last resort.

From a quick search, it look like netgear devices has really some problem with ubuntu..

This is `Broadcom BCM43231` chip, so please  give a try to [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers) (specifically [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/60395/35775))

**I recommend a full reinstall of ubuntu to get rid of all changes by ndiswrapper**

---

Another reference of the same chip and NetGear USB 
[Getting Ubuntu to recognize a BCM43231 network card what is up with terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/276321/getting-ubuntu-to-recognize-a-bcm43231-network-card-what-is-up-with-terminal)

As a last resort, if you have to go with the ndiswrapper way , follow this - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11199585

&

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ndiswrapper/index.php?title=Netgear_WNA3100