# how to use ndiswrapper to install wnda3100 v2 adaptor driver

Tags: wireless, ndiswrapper, netgear

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr and I am a newbie.

I am using an older desktop Dell Dimension E520 and WNDA3100 v2 adaptor for the WIFI.

I have tried using the WINE program to install the "Netgear WNDA3100v2 Genie program". Apparently it does not work at all.

I have installed Ndiswrapper, and downloaded the "bcmn43xx64.inf" and "bcmwlhigh5.inf". Moreover, I put these two .inf files into the download folder.

Could anyone show me the steps showing how to use Ndiswrapper to install the inf in the terminal?

I have tried using "sudo ndiswrapper -i .inf. But up to no avail.

Thanks in advance!

---

I did what you instructed me to do.

but the error came up:

Couldn't open bcmn43xx64.inf No such file or directory at /usr/sbin/ndiswrapper
-1.9 line 162

any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Please open a terminal and change directories to the location of the files:

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

Install the driver:

```
sudo ndiswrapper -i bcmn43xx64.inf
sudo ndiswrapper -ma
sudo modprobe ndiswrapper
```

Check:

```
ndiswrapper -l
```

If all has gone well, it will report that the driver is installed and the hardware is present. If your wireless doesn't start as expected, check for messages in the log:

```
dmesg | grep ndis
```

Comment: Thank you , but it did not work.

Comment: What did the message log that I requested have to say?

Comment: I'm getting [this output](http://pastebin.com/KEskU08L) when trying to get the driver for bcmwlhigh5 to work. Any clue to what the problem might be?

Comment: @PaulLammertsma Please start your own new question.

Comment: @chili555 Sure, no problem. I thought perhaps the problems might be related.

Comment: It seems there's already a question about the [Netgear N-300 here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146576/how-to-install-netgear-n-300-uab-adapter-wna3100-on-ubuntu-12-04), although the accepted answer isn't very helpful.

Comment: @PaulLammertsma That's actually a very good answer!